# How to retain Focus of the first row after sorting and searching in the datagrid?

Tags: wpf

When my datagrid loads up I am able to get the focus of the first row by providing selected index=0 in the xaml but when I perform searching the focus gets lost so I want focus to be retain at the first row no matter I do sorting and searching on the datagrid.
Here is my code that searches particular thing in the datagrid.

```
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox STB = (TextBox)sender;
            this.SearchValue = STB.Text;


            //ContentPresenter CP = (ContentPresenter)STB.TemplatedParent;
            //DataGridColumnHeader DGCH = (DataGridColumnHeader)CP.TemplatedParent;
            //DataGridColumn DGC = DGCH.Column;
            //this.ColumnName = DGC.Header.ToString();


            this.Datalist.Filter = this.CustomeFilter;
            DataGrid dataGrid = this as DataGrid;

            dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(
    dataGrid.Items[0], dataGrid.Columns[0]);
            dataGrid.BeginEdit();
        }
```

In above code I am trying to get the focus of the current cell but all in vain.

```
private bool CustomeFilter(object item)
{

    SymbolData ltpObj = item as SymbolData;
    //WpfApplication1.Model.LtpMessage ltpObj = item as WpfApplication1.Model.LtpMessage;
    string values = (string)ltpObj.Symbol.ToString();
    values = values.ToUpper();
    //return values.StartsWith(this.SearchValue.ToString().ToUpper());
    if (values.StartsWith(this.SearchValue.ToString().ToUpper()))
    { return true; }
    else
        return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read this:

**How to programmatically select and focus a row or cell in a DataGrid in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/

You can select and focus a row or cell of a `DataGrid` programmatically and get the same behaviour as when using the mouse by accessing the visual user interface elements of the `DataGrid` control and calling the `UIElement.Focus()` method on a particular `DataGridCell` object as described in the blog post above. There are code samples included.

You cannot simply set the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` property of the `DataGrid` to focus the row or cell though.